# Passing SQLContext between classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a main class in a file which creates a `sqlContext` object. However, I have numerous classes which utilize `sqlContext`, yet I can't find a good way to pass it between classes. The main issue is that I need to call 
`import sqlContext.implicits._`, and I cannot put this `import` statement as part of the object variables.

I have tried to do this within the corresponding methods (where a `sqlContext` is passed in) and by creating a new object, but these do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get sqlContext singleton from Dataframe:

```
val dataframe = //init dataframe

import dataframe.sqlContext.implicits._
```